# Adding quotes to variating characters in bash

Tags: bash, sed, influxdb, influx-line-protocol

I am trying to use the sed function in order to add double quotes for anything in between a matched pattern and a comma to break of the pattern. At the moment I am extracting the following data from cloudflare and I am trying to modify it to line protocol;

```
count=24043,clientIP=x.x.x.x,clientRequestPath=/abc/abs/abc.php
count=3935,clientIP=y.y.y.y,clientRequestPath=/abc/abc/abc/abc.html
count=3698,clientIP=z.z.z.z,clientRequestPath=/abc/abc/abc/abc.html
```

I have already converted to this format from JSON output with a bunch of sed functions to modify it, however, I am unable to get to the bottom of it to put the data for clientIP and clientRequestPath in inverted commas.

My expected output has to be;

```
count=24043,clientIP="x.x.x.x",clientRequestPath="/abc/abs/abc.php"
count=3935,clientIP="y.y.y.y",clientRequestPath="/abc/abc/abc/abc.html"
count=3698,clientIP="z.z.z.z",clientRequestPath="/abc/abc/abc/abc.html"
```

This data will be imported into InfluxDB, count will be a float whilst clientIP and clientRequestPath will be strings, hence why I need them to be in inverted commas as at the moment I am getting errors since they arent as they should be.

Is anyone available to provided to adequate 'sed' function to do is?

Comment: Why not `sed 's/\(clientIP=\)\([^,]*\)\(,clientRequestPath=\)\(.*\)/\1"\2"\3"\4"/' file` ?

Comment: A robust way would be to build the desired output directly from the JSON with `jq`

Comment: @M.NejatAydin This works perfectly well, It also helped me shorten my code as well without having to use multiple sed. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/=([^0-9][^,]*)/="\1"/g' file
```

Enclose any string following a `=` does not begin with a integer upto a `,` in double quotes, globally.

Comment: Awesome! it does work, however, only for the clientRequestPath. Since the IP starts with a number, the sed detects it as an integer and does not quote it. I need the IP to be read a string as well.

I tried to use your command with a pipeline and sed -E 's/clientIP=([^,]*)/="\1"/g'

It worked however I ended up loosing 'clientIP'. outout; 

count=24043,="x.x.x.x",clientRequestPath="/abc/abc/abc.php"

Answer (score 0):

here is a solution using a SED script to allow for multiple operations on a source file.

assuming your source data is in a file "from.dat"

create a sed script to run multiple commands

```
cat script.sed
s/clientIP=/clientIP=\"/
s/,clientRequestPath/\",clientRequestPath/
```

execute multiple-command sed script on data file redirecting the output file "to.dat"

```
sed -f script.sed from.dat > to.dat

cat to.dat  (only showing one line)
count=24043,clientIP="x.x.x.x",clientRequestPath=/abc/abs/abc.php
```